# Parsing a log file and inserting into mySQL DB

Tags: mysql, bash

I am currently tasked with writing up a script which will parse through our log file of mySQL errors and exceptions, and then insert them into a database.

The general format of the log file is:

```
POSPER ERRORS: 
01 Jan 2014 11:33:23,931 ERROR LazyInitializationException:42 - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.data.moredata.CashRegister.tickets, no session or session was closed
```

There are many more lines, but this is just an example of how the error log is currently formatted.The posper errors header only appears once, and subsequent lines are simply more errors.

What I need to do with this script is insert errors into the table I have created with the fields: client_name, timestamp, error_message and error_from (either Posper or a something else. In the example above it is posper).

So how exactly am I supposed to break down the data on each line, assign it to individual mySQL fields, and then insert it into the database? Keep in mind the log file will have many lines, so it will have to execute multiple times. I have already set up the table with the appropriate fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a table in the required format and use `LOAD DATA INFILE` from mysql to get it in there. That is all.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen interesting, I'll look into the syntax of the whole thing. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like a MySQL log file, it looks a Java application log file. And I would be wary of using `LOAD DATA INFILE` - it wil bite you on the bum when you least expect it. You'll need to parse the data is you want to be able to index at least the timestamp field. Also, unless you are very confident of the format of the log entries then you'll need to escape the values before interpolating into an SQL statement. A generic scripting language is not going to cut it - I would recommend Perl, PHP or Python with the relevant MySQL support module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Norbert van Nobelen mentioned, you should use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. There are a few techniques that you will need to deal with your particular log format. Space in your log sometimes is a delimiter and sometimes is not. You can deal with it by using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''` in combination with the user variable syntax and MySQL string functions to do the parsing. For example can do something like this (tested example on your sample line):

```
create table log (ts datetime, msg text);
load data infile '/tmp/log.txt' into table log  
  fields terminated by '@@@' (@l) 
  set ts=str_to_date(
    substring_index(@l,'ERROR',1),'%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s,%f'),
      msg=substring_index(@l, 'ERROR', -1);
```

You may need additional tricks to deal with the lines that do not follow the common pattern, but I hope this gives you a start.

Comment: This is great, thank you.